# Is it possible to invert this numpy einsum operation?

Tags: numpy-einsum

Is it possible to invert this einsum operation so I get back the input psi4d from it's output psi1 and psi2?

```
psi1 = np.einsum('jqik->ij', psi4d)                
psi2= np.einsum('kiqj->ij', psi4d)
```

I've tried  all  permutations (24x24) to reconstruct psi4d being s1 ans s2 two letters  and sr 4 letters from 'ijkq' einsum pattern

`psi4dreconstruct = np.einsum(s1 +','+ s2 + '->' + sr, psi2, psi1)`

Answer (score 0):

No, in general this is not possible (unless you have some dimensions of size 1 or some other hidden properties you did not mention). Proof :

Let the shape `psi4d` be `(J, Q, I, K)`. This means it has a total of `J*Q*I*K` entries. Therefore `psi1` will have `J*K` entries, and `psi2` will have `Q*K` entries. This means combined they will have `J*K + Q*K` entries. Now we have

```
J*K + Q*K <= 2*max(J*K, Q*K) < 4*max(J*K, Q*K) <= J*Q*I*K   (assuming J,Q,I,K >= 2)
```

So we have more numbers to recover than we have numbers given in `psi1` and `psi2` combined. By the [pigeon-hole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) this means we do not have enough information to recover `psi4d`.

Comment: I discovered that the way is first make the two 2d psi's, then make the 4d with them, and now can be recovered because I know the sum of both 2D psi's, witch is used to divide the 2D  reconstruction(psi2d1 is divided by sum initial  psi2d2 and psi2d2 by sum of initial psi2d1), If I make small changes in the 4D, it will no be so  bad ( lol...maybe have some relation with entropy increasing in universe )

Comment: Could you please post a snippet that shows how your reconstruction works for some arbitrary `psi4d` as your own answer? That way we could verify it, and other people having the same problem could learn from your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code, that creates two 2d psi, then merge both to 4d, and then restore to 2d using the sum. The error is small (e-13 e-14)

```
import numpy as np
def make2DGaussian(N,L,k,pos,sigma=0.06):
    # p is momentum, k is the wave number that is the# spatial frequency
    # with respect to spatial extent of the simulation        
    p = k * 2.0 * np.pi / L        
    X = L*np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5 - 1.0/N, N)
    Y1, X1 = np.meshgrid(X, X)    
    
    pf = np.exp(1j*p[0]*X1 + 1j*p[1]*Y1)
    gaussian = pf * np.exp(-((X1/L+pos[0]/2.)/sigma)**2/2.0                                    
                  - ((Y1/L-pos[1]/2.)/sigma)**2/2.0 )    
    return gaussian/np.sqrt(np.sum(gaussian*np.conj(gaussian)))


N=32
L=2.
sigma=0.06
pos1=np.array([-0.2,-0.4])
pos2=np.array([0.3,0.4])
k1=np.array([10.0,4.3])
k2=np.array([8.0,2.5])
psi2dA = make2DGaussian(N,L, k1 , pos1,sigma)
psi2dB = make2DGaussian(N,L, k2 , pos2,sigma)
sumA=np.sum(psi2dA) # get the sum for later restore
sumB=np.sum(psi2dB)

psi4d=np.einsum('jq,ki->ijkq', psi2dA, psi2dB)

# restore 2d from 4d using sumA and sumB
psi2dAback = np.einsum('jqik->ij', psi4d) /sumA
psi2dBback = np.einsum('kiqj->ij', psi4d) /sumB
d = np.sum(np.abs(psi2dB-psi2dAback))
print(d)
d = np.sum(np.abs(psi2dA-psi2dBback))
print(d)
```

output the difference from original and reconstruction:
6.442333575092455e-13
5.984739289962342e-14

So I can apply potentials in 2d mode, then convert to 4d and to make the time evolution step, that is where the particles interact, so maybe their personal action's are changed because they share space in 4D.

Comment: It's nice that you figured out a solution, but I'd like to point out that this solution has very little in common with what you've asked. What you've asked is impossible to solve in general while your solution is for a much more narrow problem with a lot more assumptions that you failed to mention in your initial question. Please take care in the future to accurately describe everything that is needed while removing all unnecessary information in the sense of an [MCVE]. Otherwise the complete Q&A is worthless, and just a waste of time for everyone involved.

Comment: ok, it's impossible because we need at least one number (sum psi 1 or psi 2), because there are infinite combinations  of psi1 and 2 that give  the same psi4d. If we take any random number to deconstruct psi4d we will have two 2d psi's with same  probabilities  but not the same complex's.